# Clickable HeroCard location Images

Tags: node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

Hero card contains array of CardImages, which data was returned by [Microsoft BotBuilder-Location](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Location) and bot framework rendering cards. I have to make images(locations) clickable. Where can we include required changes and how we make images clickable.

Comment: Is Mandar's answer acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Buttons Feature of the HeroCard , you can use the Image to be displayed for the button and then you can configure the image to be clickable, or another option is to set the **Tap** Property of the CardImage object